# Easily access class variable in function in global scope

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an object:

```
var long_object_name = {
  'init':function(){

    this.properties.the_screen_size[0] = window.innerWidth;
    this.properties.the_screen_size[1] = window.innerHeight;

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      long_object_name.properties.the_screen_size[0] = window.innerWidth;
      long_object_name.properties.the_screen_size[1] = window.innerHeight;
    }, false);
  },
  'properties':{
    'the_screen_size':[]
  }
}
```

So I want to store the screen size in a variable that changes when the user changes the window size.

The problem is that in the re-size event function I've to type the "long_object_name" to “reach” the "properties" object. So my question is, is there any way to “reach” the "properties" object in another way, e.g. like `this.properties` but `this` doesn't work in this case, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var long_object_name = {
  'init':function(){

    var ss = this.properties.the_screen_size;

    ss[0] = window.innerWidth;
    ss[1] = window.innerHeight;

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      ss[0] = window.innerWidth;
      ss[1] = window.innerHeight;
    }, false);
  },
  'properties':{
    'the_screen_size':[]
  }
}
```

Comment: @GGG: Ah, I see we were thinking alike. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
var long_object_name = {
  'init':function(){

    var screenSize = this.properties.the_screen_size;

    screenSize[0] = window.innerWidth;
    screenSize[1] = window.innerHeight;

    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
      screenSize[0] = window.innerWidth;
      screenSize[1] = window.innerHeight;
    }, false);
  },
  'properties':{
    'the_screen_size':[]
  }
}
```